# Changing turtle background image a 2nd time causes the turtle window to be unresponsive

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

In my code I've written a definition to change the background of the turtle after an action is completed. The definition to me looks ok and I don't see any issues with it but when the action is completed and the background image is suppose to change, the turtle window becomes unresponsive. Here is the definition that I'm talking about:

```
if default.distance(pickaxe) < 10:
        screen.clearscreen()
        wn.bgpic('TrumpTowersInside.gif')
```

And if the rest of the code is needed for whatever reason, here is the rest of the code for my turtle-based game:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
    print(x, y)

def drag(x, y):
    default.ondrag(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    default.goto(x, y)

    if default.distance(scar) < 40:
        default.shape('defaultscar.gif')
        scar.hideturtle()
        mini.hideturtle()
        pickaxe.showturtle()

    if default.distance(mini) < 40:
        banshee.goto(-200,200)
        banshee.showturtle()
        banshee.speed(0)
        for x in range(200):
            banshee.forward(1)
            banshee.right(90)
            banshee.forward(1)
            banshee.left(90)
        banshee.shape('banshee.gif')
        banshee.left(90)
        banshee.forward(50)
        scar.hideturtle()
        mini.hideturtle()
        banshee.shape('bansheescar.gif')
        default.shape('defaultdead.gif')

    if default.distance(pickaxe) < 10:
        screen.clearscreen()
        wn.bgpic('TrumpTowersInside.gif')


    default.ondrag(drag)

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(500, 500)
wn.bgpic('TrumpTowers.gif')
wn.register_shape('default.gif')
wn.register_shape('scar.gif')
wn.register_shape('defaultscar.gif')
wn.register_shape('mini.gif')
wn.register_shape('defaultgliding.gif')
wn.register_shape('banshee.gif')
wn.register_shape('bansheescar.gif')
wn.register_shape('defaultdead.gif')
wn.register_shape('pickaxe.gif')

scar = Turtle('scar.gif', visible=False)
scar.speed(-1)
scar.color('pink')
scar.penup()
scar.left(90)
scar.forward(50)
scar.showturtle()

mini = Turtle('mini.gif', visible=False)
mini.speed(-1)
mini.color('pink')
mini.penup()
mini.forward(60)
mini.showturtle()

default = Turtle('default.gif', visible=False)
default.shapesize(2)
default.speed(1)
default.penup()
default.left(90)
default.backward(50)
default.showturtle()

default.ondrag(drag)

banshee = Turtle('defaultgliding.gif', visible=False)
banshee.shapesize(2)
banshee.speed(1)
banshee.penup()
# banshee.showturtle()

pickaxe = Turtle('pickaxe.gif', visible=False)
pickaxe.pu()
pickaxe.forward(10)
pickaxe.left(90)
pickaxe.forward(50)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that you call `screen.clearscreen()` instead of the expected `wn.clearscreen()` or simply `wn.clear()`.  The `screen` symbol is not defined in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `clear()` is clear on this:

> Reset TurtleScreen to its initial state: white background,
>       no backgroundimage, no eventbindings and tracing on.

All of your event bindings (i.e. `ondrag()`) are undone by the `clear()` so you have redo them.

**UPDATE**

The screen's `clear()` method (aka `clearscreen()` fuction) is more severe than the documentation might lead one to believe.  It seems to destroy all user created turtles and resets the default turtle to its initial state.

The screen's `.reset()` method isn't much better -- you get to keep your turtles but they lose all the attributes you set.

As an alternative to clearing or resetting the screen, I suggest you ask the turtles to `clear()` to clean up any drawing if the pen was down and then move them to new locations or `home()`.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drag(x, y):
    default.ondrag(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    default.goto(x, y)

    if default.distance(pickaxe) < 10:
        wn.bgpic('TrumpTowersInside.gif')
        pickaxe.hideturtle()  # should move it elsewhere

    default.ondrag(drag)

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(500, 500)
wn.bgpic('TrumpTowers.gif')

default = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
default.color('red')
default.shapesize(2)
default.penup()
default.left(90)
default.backward(50)
default.showturtle()

default.ondrag(drag)

pickaxe = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
pickaxe.color('green')
pickaxe.penup()
pickaxe.forward(10)
pickaxe.left(90)
pickaxe.forward(50)
pickaxe.showturtle()

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can I fix the background not updating as well? Because with or without the clear command the background doesn't update and still goes unresponsive. I only added the clear command as a desperate attempt to try and fix this issue.

Comment: @MistxOli, the screen's `clear()` method is more severe than the documentation might lead one to believe -- I've updated my answer with an explanation and suggestions.